# JBoss can't read properties file in Windows

Tags: java, windows-7, jboss

We are trying increase the scope of operating system compatibility for our web application.  Our application is Java EE with JSPs, Servlets, and EJBs.  The application runs on JBoss AS.  We are able to successfully deploy our application on a Linux operating system.  However, we are having a problem on Windows.

The problem we are running into occurs when JBoss is starting.  We are receiving the follwing exception:

```
Loading properties from foo.properties
Error: can't read foo.properties file, all services will be disabled.
```

We have tried changing the permissions to allow full access and made sure there is a consistent owner of all of the directories and subdirectories, but we still receive the same error message.

Currently, clear answers to the following questions would help us make some progress:

1. Is this a known problem for JBoss when it is trying to read properties files?
2. Are there any possible workarounds we should try to find a solution?

Comment: How are you referencing the properties file ? The only obvious difference between Linux and Windows would be the path name.

Comment: Windows-7 has whole lot of restrictions on permissions. Check this link if it may help you http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/unable-to-delete-a-folder-in-windows-7-getting/ac9ebc1c-b5c8-4203-8c43-f96c1892250a

Comment: Any chance you have a problem with EOL characters? Totally just a guess.

Comment: One thing that you could do would be to run [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and then start JBoss to ensure that an attempt is made to open your foo.properties file.  You might discover that you're not having a permissions error, but rather a file not found error, like @Kevin suggests above.

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe that this is your custom message. So, the problem is in your application / environment.

Unfortunately you have not provided enough information that allows to identify exact problem. But here are the tips on the top of my head.

1. Check the file path. Are you sure it exists on your machine?
2. Check the properties files. Although I do not really believe it is the reason, check which newline symbol is used? The Linux `\n` or Windows `\r\n`?
3. If still nothing works try to move the file to location that is definitely OK (from security perspective) (e.g. `c:\temp`) and try to create empty properties file. The application will probably fail because it will not find required data, but at least the error message will be different.
4. Try to examine the stack trace. I believe you have stack trace in your log file additionally to this error message.